# yii not loading header

Tags: php, yii

Hi I configure the YII framework sucessfully, 
there is application developed by some developer, 
I imported all his file and use the same DB.

now the site on localhost is working fine but the header is not loaded.

if you check the videsource of the indexpage its starting like.

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" media = "screen" href = "http://localhost/testdrive/css/common.css" />
    <script src = "http://localhost/testdrive/js/jquery.easing-1.3.js"></script>

    <!-- iosSlider plugin -->
    <script src = "http://localhost/testdrive/js/jquery.iosslider.js"></script>
<section id="banner">
```

and at the top of protecetd\view\front\site\index.php, there is php code

```
<?php
$user_Model=Yii::app()->frontUser->userload(); 
?>
```

how can i get the header?
this is first time I am using yii.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Yii can not find the layout view. See your controller layout property. This layout can be placed in views/layouts, or may be in protecetd/view/front/layouts. It depends on your app structure. If you use different platform (windows and linux) may be there is a problem with layout file name case.